# I can't upload the image from url localhost to SlideModel

Tags: java, localhost, image-slider

I am creating a slidable images by using  implementation ("com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.2")

the code:
`ArrayList<SlideModel> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
ImageSlider imageSlider;
imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://192.168.48.18/Medication/images/1_first.jpeg", null));
imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://192.168.48.18/Medication/images/1_second.jpeg", null));

```
    imageSlider.setImageList(imageList, ScaleTypes.CENTER_INSIDE);`
```

it works fine if it was online image (online url) but does not upload the image in the local host(always says  upload....error)
can you please tell me why ? is there any solutions?

I tried

`ArrayList<SlideModel> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
ImageSlider imageSlider;
imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://192.168.48.18/Medication/images/1_first.jpeg", null));
imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://192.168.48.18/Medication/images/1_second.jpeg", null));

```
    imageSlider.setImageList(imageList, ScaleTypes.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

`

I expect the images to be uploaded and shown in the image slider